# Angular2: Forms with Material Design: ng-message doesn't work like it should

Tags: html, forms, angular, angular-material

Because I'm fairly new with Angular2 I've probably made a mistake to do with data binding from the .html sheet to the .ts file but I can't work the current problem out. I have a form with an input field and this field has the required -and maxlength-tag. I have these restrictions display an error when not followed by using Material Design. And I have a button to post the input.

```
<form name="postFeedForm">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="long-td">
            <md-input-container class="md-block | long-inputfield">
              <input mdInput name="newDescription" [(ngModel)]="newDescription" #description placeholder="What's up?" required maxlength="150">
              <md-hint align="end">{{description.value.length}} / 150</md-hint>
              <div ng-messages="postFeedForm.description.$error" ng-show="postFeedForm.description.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">Please enter a description</div>
                <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Exceeded the maximum characters {{description.value.length}} / 150</div>
              </div>
            </md-input-container>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button md-button class="text-upper | spikes_red" type="submit" (click)="post()">Post</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

[image: My result]

I'm not sure about the "#description"-tag but without it I get an error. The problem is that I've followed different examples and I probably mixed them up. What I'm trying to do can be found here (including Code Pen): https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

[image: Correct result]

The .ts file:

```
export class DashboardComponent {
  newDescription: string;

  post() {
    // Post some feed
    ...
    description: this.newDescription,
    ...
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/input/input-demo.html

Comment: `ng-messages` / `ngShow` doesn't exists in Angular 2. Also, it seems like you're trying to use Material 1 (the first link), while you should use Material 2 (compartible with Angular 2).

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice me changing from Angular2 to Angular1 when I was googling a way to validate my form. Thanks for pointing that out. I've found a similar StackOverflow question now that I know where the problem lies and can probably solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to developer033 who commented on my question, I noticed that I was using code that doesn't work in Angular2, therefore the solution:

```
<form name="postFeedForm">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="long-td">
            <md-input-container class="md-block | long-inputfield">
              <input mdInput name="newDescription" [(ngModel)]="newDescription" #description placeholder="What's up?" required maxlength="150">
              <md-hint *ngIf="errorMessagePost()" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}" align="start">{{errorMessagePost()}}</md-hint>  
              <md-hint align="end">{{description.value.length}} / 150</md-hint>
            </md-input-container>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button md-button class="text-upper | spikes_red" type="submit" (click)="post()">Post</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

The .ts file:

```
export class DashboardComponent {
  newDescription: string;

  errorMessagePost() {
    if (this.newDescription === '') {
      return 'Please enter a description';
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  post() {
    // Post some feed
    ...
    description: this.newDescription,
    ...
  }
}
```

[image: Working result]

Source: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/348

I also decided to not include the "Exceeded the maximum characters"-error because I've already capped my input and it's not possible to exceed it anymore. If others use my code and decide to use that error, don't forget to define your "description" in the .ts file (otherwise your .length check won't work).

```
export class DashboardComponent {
  newDescription: string = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Now with "2.0.0-beta.3" you can use 'md-error' for error validation:

HTML:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="email" [formControl]="emailFormControl" required>
    <md-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
    This field is required
    </md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('pattern')">
    Please enter a valid email address
    </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

TS:

```
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...
const EMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
....
export class PageComponent {
....
public emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEX)]);
....
}
```